# Include template with variable in Freemarker

Tags: java, templates, freemarker

In Freemarker, I have a variable in my model, template, which has the value "index.ftl". I then have a template which looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<#include $template>
</body>
</html>
```

However, this is throwing an error:

```
Caused by: freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> [in template "template.tfl" at line 5, column 11]
```

However, if I include the variable with the standard `${template}` expression, the string "index.tpl" shows up on the page as expected. Why is this happening? And what is the correct way of including a template with a variable path?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it was a simple syntax error. It should read,

```
<#include template>
```

rather than

```
<#include $template>
```

Comment: Hadn't you been using old(ish) FreeMarker version, the error message would have contained this: "Tip: Variable references must not start with "$", unless the "$" is really part of the variable name."

Comment: Oh, thanks. I didn't know I was using an out of date version. I feel pretty silly.